# Xpath for node with multipe attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bar</artifactId>
    <version>9.9.9</version>
</project>
```

I am trying to edit the *version* value with xmlstarlet, however I am having trouble coming up with the XPath that points to that node since the parent node  has multiple attributes I can't seem to get my way around it.

I tried the following, however I get *Invalid expression* errors:

```
xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -L -u "/project[@xmlns=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 and @xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance and @xsi:schemaLocation=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd]/version" -v 10.10.10 ./file.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlns` attributes are [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) definitions. The one without a colon defines the default namespace. XPath doesn't support default namespaces so you have to refer to it explicitly. Recent versions of XMLStarlet (1.5.0+) bind the default namespace to "_" so you can do this:

```
xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -L -u "/_:project/_:version" -v 10.10.10 ./file.xml
```

You can bind namespaces explicitly like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N pom=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 --omit-decl -L -u "/pom:project/pom:version" -v 10.10.10 ./file.xml
```

See also, [Section 5.1 of the manual](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap all attribute values within single-quotes :

```
"/project[@xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' and @xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' and @xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd']/version"
```